# Create Parse objects fail when Class Level Permission says only owner can create the class

Tags: parse-platform

#### Issue Description

Let's say I have a Parse "Diary class" with a **text** and **owner** property, where **owner** is a pointer.

Using default Class Level Permissions (Pointer permissions) on the dashboard, I imagine anyone can create new objects and claims that they are owned by another random user, like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"text":"hacked","owner": {"__type": "Pointer","className": "_User","objectId": "ANYTHING_THE_HACKER_WANT"}}' \
  http://server.com/parse/classes/Diary
```

So I try to modify the CLP on the dashboard, hoping that diaries that belongs to a user should only be created by the user. But I couldn't get this to work.

#### Steps to reproduce

1) Configure Class Level Permissions on a class like this:

[image: ![Image of CLP](https://imgur.com/a/rMt5T)]

2) Try to create new objects, saying they are owned by the logged in user:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: r:4613f36ba383022378780d4c2bcdf1cd" \
  -d '{"text":"...","owner": {"__type": "Pointer","className": "_User","objectId": "CSosrTAkxL"}}' \
  https://server.com/parse/classes/Diary
```

#### Expected Results

Diary objects should be created successfully since the person calling this is the owner. I.e. the session token matches the objectId of the owner?

#### Actual Outcome

It returns error instead:

```
{"code":119,"error":"Permission denied for action create on class Diary."}
```

Why? Am I expecting a right behaviour?

Comment: This is just some poor design / UX. The create permission for pointers on a CLP is virtually meaningless. Only specific users, roles, and public can practically be allowed Create permissions. Pointer permissions require the object to already be in the database to be used. Kinda silly, honestly. Ideally, the UI would be updated to have the Create option for pointer permissions be grayed out and unchecked, to make it clear that's not a possible permission to grant a pointer on an object that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Totally agree. It is a misleading UI implying that the "owner" can create objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Create box for Public. Pointer permissions for CLPs affect only the specific object *in the database*. Since these objects are not yet in the database, the user does not pass the CLP to be able to save this object without the master key override from cloud code.  Checking the Create box will mean any user can create one of these objects, but they must then be the Owner in order to update or delete that object.

Comment: Hi Jake thanks for clarification. Can I check with you, is it theoretically safe to allow "Public" to create objects like that? I am still quite new to Parse. It appears to me that as long as a hacker can guess/steal somebody's userId, he can create an object and says that it belongs to that guy, without even hacking the victim's login or session?

Comment: That's possible, yes. But they would then need to have a valid session in that user's name to modify the object. An alternative would be to turn off public create permissions and add a cloud function that creates these objects and returns them for the client. Then, you can validate a user session, and use `request.user` as the `Owner` of these objects. This would guarantee another user couldn't create an object on behalf of another user. Don't forget to set `{useMasterKey:true}` or your cloud code won't be able to create the object, either.

Comment: Noted. Thank you!